# Flutter Keep Container on the top while scrolling

Tags: flutter, scroll, stack

[image]

I have my screen like this.
Everything is a list view. SO I can scroll my screen. normally when I scroll everything goes up, even my header. What I want to do is, When I scroll down, I need to keep "**MY HEADER CONTAINER**" always on the top below the APP BAR.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558266/how-to-fixed-container-on-top-while-scrolling-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution could be removing the header from the list view

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network("https://picsum.photos/200"),
            Text("header"),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text("$index");
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: when I scroll I need to keep Text("header") on the top. In your solution it will scroll everything.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to work with Lists**

```
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("AppBar"),),
  body: Column(children:[
    Container(height: 150,child:Center(child: Text("Your header content"),)),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              trailing: Icon(Icons.check,color: Colors.green,),
              title: Text('$index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ])
);
```

**If you want to work with Containers**

```
    Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("AppBar"),),
  body:Column(children:[
    Container(
        height: 100,
        child:Center(child: Text("Your header content"),)),
    Container(
      height: 500,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/250")),
            Container(child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/250")),
            Container(child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/250"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ])
);
```

Comment: Initially I have an image top of header. So when I scroll image should go up and disappear. Then only header should be in the top

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html